# Any lightweight erlang based server supporting url parsing like tornado, and no ORM features?

Tags: url, erlang, request, yaws

I tried out YAWS and was hoping that someone has already written a URL parser / request handler on top of it. I don't want anything close to ChicagoBoss which includes an ORM as well.

Let me know if my question is not clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Try cowboy (https://github.com/extend/cowboy)

Comment: take back my words, this sounds pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have no other choice as of now, I'm gonna go with cowboy. Thanks W55tKQbuRu28Q4xv for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the basho's [Webmachine](http://webmachine.basho.com/) layered on top of a mochiweb server.

Consult [wiki](http://wiki.basho.com/Webmachine.html) if you want to discover more. Thanks basho last one is informative and comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks Keynslug. I'm just skeptical on using mochiweb and a plug-in sorta environment since they also have an ORM in their kit. What I was looking for was something like cowboy (commented above) which is pretty small and simple code to solve my question.